# Load content into DIV dependent on link id

Tags: jquery, html, load

basically, I have created multiple links with the class 'link' and they each have an id of what they represent.

I have written a JQuery script, which isn't working for me, and throws the first error:

```
    $(function() {
    $.get('pages/home.html')
    .success(function(response) {
        $('.contentblock').html(response);
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('.contentblock').html('<h1>Failed to load page(s)!</h1>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.link', function() {
        $('.contentblock').html('<div class="animatedload"></div>');

        var page = 'pages/' + $(this).attr('id') + '.html';
        $('.contentblock').hide();
        $.get(page)
        .success(function(response) {
            $('.contentblock').html(response);
        })
        .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });
        $('.contentblock').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Its throwing the .error(function()){} in the 6th line.

Please help me solve this :( Thank you for the help in advance!

EDIT: Was a server issue, not the code :)

~MCD

Comment: That error only has to do with the initial load, not with loads from clicks though, right? Also, I'm pretty sure you're specifying the success/load functions wrong, but I'll have to check.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I just hadn't seen that form of specifying handler functions. In any case, why don't you include textStatus and errorThrown in your output, to help you debug? Without knowing WHY it got to the error function, it's fairly impossible to say why it didn't work.

Comment: It worked previously @crimson_penguin but now it doesnt seem too, its the same code :s

Comment: Did you do what I suggested to find out what the error is? We can't really figure out why the error is happening without knowing what the error is. Are you running it from a file, requesting another local file? If so, that doesn't work, for security reasons.

Comment: @crimson_penguin all i'm try to do is just load content from pages in another folder

Comment: Yeah, that won't work for security reasons. If it did work, then if you saved some web page from the Internet and then opened it locally, it could access all your files, which you probably wouldn't want. Put this on a server and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out @crimson_penguin was right!

It wont work for security reasons, so put it onto a server for it to work